# How to get csv data from url into panda dataframe while using authentication?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a link to csv file. This linke requires authentication. I am able to get to the file using this code below:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv
from io import StringIO
url = 
'https://prowl.pricespider.com/client/reports.phpr=urlListV2&clientId=1463242t32341&output=csv'
user = 'XXXXXXX'
password = 'XXXXXXX'
resp = requests.get(url, auth=(user, password)).content
resp
```

However, when i check response it seems that i am getting meta data from the csv but not the content.

Something like this:

```
/>\n    <script src="/build/js/main.js?v=1154c867ef16ad54fe0413e5a76bd438" data- 
version="75cae4b8ed42f7c89deeb2eb1270aca25188f364"></script>    <link type="text/css" 
rel="stylesheet" href="/build/css/main.css?v=1154c867ef16ad54fe0413e5a76bd438....."
```

This is just small snippet of the response, but it cantinas things like color of the sheets, background, fonts etc.

I tried using this line of code:
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(resp).decode('utf-8'))

hoping it will decode the file and give me the content but it is not working. I am getting error message:
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Any idea why am i getting metta data and how do I get the content of this csv file into panda dataframe?

- UPDATE:
  The reason I am getting that response i mentioned is because the script is loading the "log in" page while not even using the credentials. It seems that page just loads and never prompt for username and password.
  Any idea how to go about this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use pandas only, or could you also use beautiful soup and then pass in the data to df.read_html?

Comment: I can try that. however, i do need to end up with dataframe and this is something i will have to build as an ETL later on as automated script. I used beautiful soup before but i always find it troublesome if things in format change.